# QTableWidget Checkbox get state and location

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qtablewidget

How to get state of all checkbox and get row and column of checked?
Onclick PushButton function.

```
    QTableWidget *t = ui->tableWidget;
    t->setRowCount(2);
    t->setColumnCount(2);

    QStringList tableHeader;
    tableHeader<<"item01"<<"item02";
    t->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tableHeader);

    for (int i = 0; i < t->rowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t->columnCount(); j++) {
            QWidget *pWidget = new QWidget();
            QHBoxLayout *pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
            QCheckBox *pCheckBox = new QCheckBox();
            pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
            pLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
            pLayout->addWidget(pCheckBox);
            pWidget->setLayout(pLayout);
            t->setCellWidget(i, j, pWidget);
        }
    }
```

And when I clicked the button, I need get all selected elements with rows, columns of each.

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    // Code here    

    // For example: Selected ["item01", 2]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply iterate over all cell widgets:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t->rowCount(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < t->columnCount(); j++) {
        QWidget *pWidget = t->cellWidget(i, j);
        QCheckBox *checkbox = pWidget->findChild<QCheckBox *>();
        if (checkbox && checkbox->isChecked())
            qDebug() << t->horizontalHeaderItem(j)->text() << i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've programmed with Qt, but I believe there is not really good way of doing this.  I've done all of these solutions with success.

1) Iterate through all the cell widgets like svlasov's answer says.  This has some scalability issues.

2) Create hash maps where the pointer to the button is the key and the indices you want are the values.  You can get which button was clicked with `QObject::sender()`.

3) Store the indices you want as properties on the button when you create the buttons (see [setProperty() in QObject's documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qobject.html)).  For example,

```
button->setProperty("x index", x);
```

In your `slot`, use `QObject::sender()` to get the pointer to the button and then call

```
button->property("x");
```

I've generally found the third option to be the cleanest and best performing.

Note that these answers also work for QTreeWidgets and QListWidgets.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just start learning Qt. The SLOTs will study later.

Comment: on_pushButton_clicked() is a `slot`,  naming it this way causes it to automatically be one.  It's a lot to take in at once, come back to this answer after you've learned a bit more and it will make more sense to you.